# Performing a time calculation inside a Linq query

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a Linq to Entities query that pulls data from a DB. One of those fields is a timezone offset. I am trying to figure out how to convert that offset to a the real time based on the current time of the server. The intent is to show the actual time of the contact on a web page.

```
from c in Contacts
              .Where(a => a.LastName.Contains("Anderson"))               
                     select new
                    {
                        Id = c.Id,
                        Surname= c.LastName,
                        TheirTime = c.TimeZoneOffset                           
                    }
```

For this example the c.TimeZoneOffset would be -6 from UTC (i.e. US Central Time Zone). What I want is something like DateTime.UTCOffset(-6) but it needs to be part of the query if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **DbFunctions**.

```
using System.Data.Entity; //namespace

from c in Contacts.Where(a => a.LastName.Contains("Anderson"))               
                   select new
                   {
                       Id = c.Id,
                       Surname= c.LastName,
                       TheirTime = c.TimeZoneOffset,
                       CalculatedTime = DbFunctions.AddMinutes(c.SavedUtcTime,x.UtcOffsetInMinutes)                  
                   }
```

This assumes you have the 'SavedUtcTime' and 'UtcOffsetInMinutes' properties in your model.

Hope this helps.